# Prevent Windows form from Closing with options yes/no

Tags: vb.net

I would like to provide the user the option to either run the application on the background or close it permanently when the form's close button is clicked. At the moment, when the use clicks 'Yes' the dialog box reappears and when clicking yes for a second time the application exits. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) 
  Handles Me.FormClosing

    Dim result = DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like the backup tool 
 to run in the background?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

    If result = True Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.Hide()
    ElseIf result = False Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you should start with Option Strict.  you have a YESNO dialog, but evaluate it as `True`.  when you call Application.Exit, it will also want to close the form - do nothing for the Else should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing the Form.DialogResult with the return value of MessageBox.Show().  It will always be False.  Which makes you call Application.Exit(), that fires the FormClosing event again.  Proper code ought to look like:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Would you like the backup tool to run in the background?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    Application.Exit()   '' Not that clear that this is really necessary!!
End Sub
```

Do keep in mind that you've got a hidden window that the user can't get back to easily unless you add code to revive it.

Comment: Yes, I have the app running in the system tray with notifications. Great answer.

Comment: Don't do it this way.  Just set a Boolean variable to True when you get the Exit command from the context menu.  The "I really want to exit" command.  You can test it in FormClosing.  Otherwise a good example why it is *always* important to explain what you want to accomplish when you ask a question.